# What should I do with closed questions?

Tags: discussion

I had a question get closed as a duplicate. Should I delete it? Should I accept the one answer someone gave for the question? I'm not really sure how to handle these.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to delete it, and you don't need to accept the answer.  Don't worry much about it.

A moderator (or community voting) may eventually delete a closed question, but questions closed as duplicates are often left as-is because they provide alternate question titles useful for others who are searching for an answer to a similar question.  (Google will index all of the versions.)

i.e. The differently-worded duplicate serves as an alternate way to find the original question.